# Incomplete address sanitizer (asan) output on MSVC Win10

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, address-sanitizer

I've followed this documentation to run a minimal MSVC compiled application with asan enabled:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan?view=msvc-170#command-prompt

When running the executable on Windows 10, using the latest msvc v16.11.7 (we also tested 2 earlier versions on a different pc), the runtime output only contains the first 2 lines.

So I can see:

```
AddressSanitizer: global-buffer-overflow on address 0x006fbed0 at pc 0x00691155 bp 0x00cafb14 sp 0x00cafb08
WRITE of size 4 at 0x006fbed0 thread T0
```

But I get no information beyond these lines, program execution is halted and I must press "ctrl+c" to quit on the command line.

I expect to see exactly what the Microsoft documentation is showing, a full report with the stack trace.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you running a debug build? Is the debug information available when running?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I follow the MS example, where Debug or Release is not specified, so it will be a release build. Note that at first only Release was supported but the version of MSVC I use supports both Debug and Release builds. The example in the link is only 5 lines of code and 1 compile command directly executed on the "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019", it should work as shown but it doesn't.